# Top border does not appear across the full length of the navbar (small screens)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Link to website:

[website](https://www.theplanter.nl/blog/page/tools/zaaikalender.htm)

The navbar links collapse into a hamburger menu dropdown on smaller screens and I created a CSS property for the top border `.navbar { border-top: 3px solid rgba(55,175,75,1.00); }` which is applied to the navbar. Now when the screen becomes smaller the hamburger menu button appears to be overlapping the green border-top of the navbar!

Perhaps this is a bit of a beginners issue but I tried everything I could think about: Margins to move the button a little lower (now it overlaps the bottom border too), removing background-color or to make it transparent using `rgba(0,0,0,0.00)` (does not seem to work at all)...

Any suggestions are very much appreciated...

**Here's what it looks like:**

[image]

Green top border does not show across the full length of the navbar, looks as if the hamburger menu button having a white background is overlapping the navbar top border.

Comment: Could you share your html and css with us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
margin-top: 0px;
height: 100%;
```

to the hamburger icon.

Comment: Thanks, this does solve the problem! But now the navbar link dropdowns are also stretched in height. Perhaps adding a new class to the navbar icon would help? Going to test it right now.

Comment: Confirmed! Adding a new class to only the hamburger LINK (not the icon) and giving this class a 100% height solves the problem :D

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
margin-top: 0.5px;
height: calc(100% - 5px);
```

to the hamburger menu Icon

Answer (score 0):

I go to your website and resolve your problem.
add padding-top to `.navbar` and subtract from `padding-top` in `.navbar a` like following :

```
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    z-index: 2;
    /* background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.85); */
    /* border-top: 2px solid rgba(55,175,75,1.00); */
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(55,175,75,1.00);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.navbar a {
   float: left;
   font-size: 16px;
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: rgba(55,175,75,1.00);
   padding: 30px 16px 11px 16px;
   transition: 0.25s;
   transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

I add `padding-top: 2px` to `.navbar` and change `padding: 33px 16px 11px 16px` to `padding: 30px 16px 11px 16px`

Comment: This removes the icon and adds a white space to the right of my page, I don't know why. Styling the bootstrap navbar is a bit tricky... :(

Comment: @JonaGoldapple I didn't have this problem